# Prevent ajax call on select2 click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How can I prevent `ajax` call to retrieve `select2` drop down items on click of `select2` user interface element? I want to retrieve `select2` drop down items only when I type in search box. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
$("#ddlItems").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 0,
  width: '450px',
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: "Select",
  id: function (data) { return { id: data.Id }; },
  ajax: { 
    quietMillis: 150,
    url: getDataUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    quietMillis: 100,
    global: false,
    data: function (term, page) {
      return {
        clientId: $("#clientID").val(),
        pageSize: 20,
        pageNum: page,
        searchTerm: term
      };
  },
  results: function (data, page) { 
      return { results: data.items, more: data.isSearchRemaining };
  }
}
```

Comment: @RanjeetSingh, i have added code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your minimumInputLength attribute.

Change it like that :

```
minimumInputLength: 1,
```

The ajax request is done when your input length >= minimumInputLength.
So it is logical that when minimumInputLength = 0 , select2 will retrieve the data using the ajax :)

You have an example on here : https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax